# My dividing sequence code does not solve all problems presented to it

Tags: java, arrays, sequence, dynamic-programming

> This problem is about sequences of positive integers a1,a2,…,aN. A subsequence of a sequence is anything obtained by dropping some of the elements. For example, 3,7,11,3 is a subsequence of 6,**3**,11,5,**7**,4,3,**11**,5,**3** , but 3,3,7 is not a subsequence of 6,3,11,5,7,4,3,11,5,3 .
>
> A fully dividing sequence is a sequence a1,a2,…,aN where ai divides aj whenever i < j. For example, 3,15,60,720 is a fully dividing sequence.
>
> Given a sequence of integers your aim is to find the length of the longest fully dividing subsequence of this sequence.
>
> Consider the sequence 2,3,7,8,14,39,145,76,320
>
> It has a fully dividing sequence of length 3, namely 2,8,320, but none of length 4 or greater.
>
> Consider the sequence 2,11,16,12,36,60,71,17,29,144,288,129,432,993 .
>
> It has two fully dividing subsequences of length 5 - (2,12,36,144,288) or (2,12,36,144,432).

To solve this problem, I have written the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class DivSeq {

  private int n, input[];

  void accept() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = sc.nextInt();
    input = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    input[i] = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();         
}

int size(int a[]) {
    //this function returns the number of non zero entries in an array
    int ctr = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i]==0)
        break;
        else
        ctr++;
    }
    return ctr;
  }

  int sequence() {
    int subseq[], pvrseq[], seq[], j, a = 1, q, k = 1, f = 0;
    subseq = new int [n]; 
    pvrseq = new int [n];
    seq = new int [n]; 
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++) {
        k = 1;
        for(int c = 0; c<seq.length; c++)
        seq[c] = 0;
        //seq has been initialized, now inserting 1st value
        seq[0] = input[i];
        //creating the sequence
        for(j = i+1; j<n; j++) {
            if(input[j]%input[i]==0) 
            seq[k++] = input[j];
        }
        //if size of sequence is 1, then there is no use of checking it
        if(size(seq)<2)
        continue;
        subseq[0] = seq[0];
        a = 1;
        while(a<size(seq)-1) {
            k = 2;
            for(int p = a; p<size(seq)-1; p++) {
                //initial value of subsequence
                if(subseq[1] == 0)
                subseq[1] = seq[p];
                //creating the subsequence
                for(q = p+1; q<size(seq); q++) {  

                    if(seq[q]%seq[p]==0) {
                        subseq[k++] = seq[q];
                        p = q-1;
                        f = 1;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(f==1 && q==size(seq)-1)
                break;
            }

            //checking the size of subsequence and previous sequence

            if(size(pvrseq)<size(subseq)) {

                 for(int y = 0; y<subseq.length; y++)
                 pvrseq[y] = subseq[y];

                 for(int y = 1; y<subseq.length; y++)
                 subseq[y] = 0;
            }
            a++;
        }           
    }

    return size(pvrseq);
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    DivSeq obj = new DivSeq();
    obj.accept();
    System.out.println(obj.sequence());
  }

}
```

This code solves some of the test cases that it is supposed to solve.

case 1: 2,3,7,8,14,39,145,76,320
        desired output = 3

case 2: 2,11,16,12,36,60,71,17,29,144,288,129,432,993
        desired output = 5

Rest of the test cases are invisible.

However, it does not solve all of them and I cannot understand why. It manages to meet only 4/11 test cases (including case 1 and case 2).

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to include the expected and actual output for your test cases.

Comment: Hello dave, I have edited it to include the test cases.

Comment: @c2yCharlie

your code is givign wrong o/p for the below cases.
**************
1
46
**************
    6
    2 4 232 8 8 464

Answer (score 1):

@LuCio and @Aldert I found an alternate way to solve the problem. Here is the code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class DivSeqUpdated {

      private int n, input[], weight[];

      void accept() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = sc.nextInt();
        input = new int[n];
        weight = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        input[i] = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
      }

      int max(int x, int y) {
        return x<y?y:x;
      }

      int sequence(int src, int a[], int n) {
        if(weight[src]==-1) {
            int i, tmp = 0;
            for(i = src+1; i<n; i++) {
                if(a[i]%a[src]==0)
                tmp = max(tmp, sequence(i,a,n));
            }
            weight[src] = tmp+1;
        }
        return weight[src];
      }

      public static void main(String [] args) {
        DivSeqUpdated obj = new DivSeqUpdated();
        obj.accept();
        for(int i = 0; i<obj.n; i++)
        obj.weight[i] = -1;
        int tmp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<obj.n; i++) 
        tmp = obj.max(tmp, obj.sequence(i,obj.input,obj.n));
        System.out.println(tmp);
      }    

  }
```

It gives a result of 11/11 tests which solves the issue. I hope this can help other users as well.

Comment: I've compared the result of your code with my code after my last update. Both solutions give the same results for 11 tests I've defined.

Comment: It is an ok answer but I do not believe it will perform that good on large arrays as it is O(n!) I believe I even can optimize my answer further, I like puzzles..

Comment: @Aldert I would love to see a more optimized code of the above.

Comment: @Aldert Sure mate...waiting for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would take a recursive approach to determine the longest subsequence of a sequence.

```
  protected static int[] subsequence(int[] seq) {
    int[] longestSub = new int[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
      int[] subAtI = subseq(subarray(seq, i));
      if (longestSub.length < subAtI.length) {
        longestSub = subAtI;
      }
    }
    return longestSub;
  }

  private static int[] subseq(int[] seq) {
    if (seq.length == 1) {
      return seq;
    }

    int[] longestSub = new int[0];
    int current = seq[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < seq.length; i++) {
      int number = seq[i];
      if (number > 0 && current > 0 && number % current == 0) {
        int[] subAtI = subseq(subarray(seq, i));
        if (longestSub.length < subAtI.length) {
          longestSub = subAtI;
        }
      }
    }

    return concat(current, longestSub);
  }

  private static int[] concat(int current, int[] sub) {
    int[] result = new int[sub.length + 1];
    result[0] = current;
    System.arraycopy(sub, 0, result, 1, sub.length);
    return result;
  }

  private static int[] subarray(int[] seq, int i) {
    int length = seq.length - i;
    int[] result = new int[length];
    System.arraycopy(seq, i, result, 0, length);
    return result;
  }
```

For a sequence iterate over each integer (`seq[i]`) and determine the subsequence for that integer (`subsequence(subarray(seq, i))`). The longest subsequence is the result.

Applying that to some example from the question:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    printLongestSub(new int[] { 2, 11, 16, 12, 36, 60, 71, 17, 29, 144, 288, 129, 432, 993 }); // [2, 12, 36, 144, 288]
    printLongestSub(new int[] { 2, 3, 7, 8, 14, 39, 145, 76, 320 }); // [2, 8, 320]
    printLongestSub(new int[] { 2 }); // [2]
    printLongestSub(new int[] { 2, 5 }); // [2]
    printLongestSub(new int[] { 5, 6, 12 }); // [6, 12]
    printLongestSub(new int[] { 5, 6, 12, 11, 33, 99 }); // [11, 33, 99]
  }

  private static void printLongestSub(int[] seq) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subsequence(seq)));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, it gives a result of 3/11 tests passed. So there is something that is lacking. I hope you can look into it.

Comment: @c2yCharlie 3/11 is a poor result :) Could you show me some of these test sequences?

Comment: No mate :( Those cases have been made invisible/hidden by the platform. Even I cannot see what those cases are. There are only two visible test cases (case 1 and case 2 as mentioned above) and your code passes them. My code seemed to pass 4/11. :(

Comment: @c2yCharlie I added the condition: `number > 0 && current > 0 && ...`